# Define a Custom Form for use in Django's ModelAdmin Add View

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to expose a Django model in admin using the ModelAdmin class. ModelAdmin seems to assume you use the same form for add and change. I'd like the add_view to use a simplified form that only lists a handful of required fields. After submission, it'll redirect to the change_view and use ModelForm's default form to render nearly all fields.

What's the easiest way to do this? I've inspected the code, but I don't see a clear way. ModelAdmin tends to refer to a single self.form reference in both the add_view and change_view. I'm thinking of overriding add_view(), but I don't want to reimplement all the code. It might be more efficient to override get_form(), but I don't see how to detect whether get_form() is being called during add_view or change_view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get_form()` is passed an `obj` parameter when called during `change_view`.  Simply detect that return the new form/tweak parameters as needed.

For example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # hide every other field apart from url
        # if we are adding
        if obj is None:
            kwargs['fields'] = ['url']
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Will force the form to only display the "url" field when adding and everything else otherwise.

Comment: This is generally the right idea, but it turns out I need to override a lot more than this. The UserAdmin class in django/contrib/auth/admin.py is a good example.